# gspread. How can I print my cell without coordinates showing up?

Tags: python-3.x, gspread

Code:

```
    Grab1 = wks.acell("A{}".format(next_row))
    print(Grab1)
```

Output:

```
<Cell R3C1 'test1'>
```

Why does it have to give me Cell R3C1... I just want test1 to print. Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Just had to add .value to the end of the first line.